# Roman to Int converts incorrectly in some cases

Tags: javascript, roman-numerals

My function looks like this:

```
let romanToInt = romanNumber => {
    if(typeof romanNumber !== 'string') throw new TypeError('Argument must be of type String');

    const values = { 'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000 };
    let sum = 0;

    romanNumber.split('').map(n => n.toUpperCase()).forEach(n => sum = (sum >= values[n]) ? sum + values[n] : values[n] - sum);

    return sum;
}

console.log(romanToInt("MCMXCVI"));
```

Most of the inputs I test with is correct, but the roman number `MCMXCVI` for example, should give me `1996`, and not `2216`, which is what I'm getting.

I found this, but I'm unsure how to implement that:

> You must separate ones, tens, hundreds, and thousands as separate
>   items. That means that 99 is XCIX, 90 + 9, but never should be written
>   as IC. Similarly, 999 cannot be IM and 1999 cannot be MIM.

Comment: *"which probably has something to do with it"* - Well yes. CM is 900, IX is 9, IV is 4, etc. Your code doesn't allow for that at all.

Comment: @nnnnnn Poor choice of words on my part. I'll edit, but I'm still unsure of how to implement that.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton wrong. Try my code with IX. It will print 9.

Comment: @nnnnnn My code prints all your example correctly.

Comment: Sorry, yes, poor choice of words on my part too: I should've said "doesn't properly allow for that" or "doesn't allow for that when following another letter" (given that when those combinations follow another letter the other letter will be a higher value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question, you need to cater to the separate items. An easy way to do this is to simply make your value set larger, and looking for multi char matches. This is possible because there are only a few combinations allowed with roman numerals. I have put a fiddle together [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0L16d944/)

```
const values = { 
  'I': 1, 
  'V': 5, 
  'X': 10, 
  'L': 50, 
  'C': 100, 
  'D': 500, 
  'M': 1000,
  'CM': 900,
  'CD': 400,
  'XC': 90,
  'XL': 40,
  'IX': 9,
  'IV': 4
};

let sum = 0;

while(romanNumber.length > 0){
  let piece = romanNumber.substring(0,2);
  if(values[piece]){
    sum += values[piece];
    romanNumber = romanNumber.substring(2);
  }else if(values[piece[0]]){
    sum += values[piece[0]];
    romanNumber = romanNumber.substring(1);
  }
}

return sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not hope to solve the problem with a simple mapping, since in Roman numerals, the meaning of a digit depends on the context. I think, many cases can be handled with something like that (instead of your line with split and map):

```
var digits = romanNumber.split('');
var i = 0;
while (i < digits.length) {
    if (i == digits.length - 1 || values[digits[i]] >= values[digits[i+1]]) {
        sum += values[digits[i]];
        i++;
    }
    else {
        sum += values[digits[i+1]] - values[digits[i]];
        i += 2;
    }
}
```

But I am not sure that it will work in all cases. It would be better to see how it is implemented in ready libraries, maybe for other languages. For example, here is an implementation for Perl: http://search.cpan.org/~chorny/Roman-1.24/lib/Roman.pm

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can implement with a one-liner mapping, because the operation depends on the comparisons of characters next to each other. However, with a simple `for` loop：

```
var chars = romanNumber.split('');
var sum = values[chars[chars.length - 1]];
for (var i = chars.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (values[chars[i + 1]] <= values[chars[i]]) {
        sum += values[chars[i]];
    } else {
        sum -= values[chars[i]];
    }
}
```

The thing is when a roman digit is smaller in value than the one to its right, you want to subtract it from the sum instead of add.